# Can I show an erb template in facebook page tab?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am trying to display an erb template inside a facebook page tab. I am successful in doing so using wordpress, but with rails I am getting this error.

FBML Error: illegal tag "body" under "fb:tab-position"

The output of wordpress and rails are exactly similar. They are generating the same html. While in case of wordpress the contents are getting displayed in tabs, in case of rails it throws an error.

Has anyone successfully implemented a facebook app with page tabs using rails.

Answer (score 2):

Is your template being rendered with a layout?  Usually the layout would have head and body tags, which you don't want in your facebook content as it's in the context of a page (facebook) that already defines the head and body.  To render a page without layout pass the :layout => false option to your render call.

Comment: Even if I do not render layout, the rendered page has body and head tags. This is thing is making me crazy.

Comment: Try a really simple test: instead of rendering the template, say "render :text => "foo", :layout => false".  This should just send the word 'foo' and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely getting an error and the body tag is getting in there from the 500.html or the 404.html.

I tried a million things and I found that I had an invalid authenticity token.  To see if this is your issue try:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

In your controller that is rendering the view.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, in a tab you can't have a 'body' tag. Are you 100% sure the Rails output doesn't somehow have it?

Basically you have to supply Facebook a stripped down HTML as they have their own 'head' and 'body' tags.

Comment: There are no html and body tags in the page source.

Comment: Getting a server error when trying to load that URL. Another possibility, can it be that there's some caching somewhere where you wouldn't want it to be?

Comment: Let me check. Thanks for the effort guys.